# If S = {1/n | n ∈ ℕ}, what is inf(S)?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

> If $S = \{1/n \mid n ∈ ℕ\}$, what is $\inf(S)$?

I believe the answer is $0$, but I'm not really sure how to prove it...does it involve using epsilon?

Comment: It does involve using $\varepsilon$.

Comment: It is zero.  What have you tried?

Comment: What is the _definition_ of $\inf(S)$?

Comment: Finding the infimum of a set usually involves using $\epsilon$. Did you ever (at lectures or as homework) calculate an infumum before?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the set is bounded below by 0, so $\inf(S)\geq 0$. Assume $\inf(S):=\varepsilon > 0$. Then by the Archimedean property of the naturals (i.e. since the naturals are not bounded above), we can find a natural $N$ s.t. $1/N < \varepsilon$, but then $\inf(S) \leq \inf(\{1/N\})<\inf(S)$, a contradiction.